# How can I curl the output of another command

Tags: bash, pipe, curl

I want to pass curl the output from awk

```
./jspider.sh http://www.mypage.com | grep 'resource' | awk '{print $4}' | curl OUTPUT_FROM_AWK | grep myString
```

How can I achieve this?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `xargs`.

```
xargs utility [argument ...]
```

> The xargs utility reads space, tab, newline and end-of-file delimited strings from the standard input and executes `utility` with the strings as arguments.

<sup>There are more parameters and options than in this shortened form, of course.</sup>

---

A general example using `curl`:

```
$ echo "http://www.google.com" | xargs curl
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.de/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

---

In your specific case, it'd look similar to the following:

```
./jspider.sh http://www.mypage.com | grep 'resource' | awk '{print $4}' | xargs curl | grep myString
```

Comment: Great! However in my case this doesn't work. If piping to "xargs echo" it also doesn't work. I guess output of jspider is too fast or sth..

Comment: In that case, consider adding to your question or creating a new question dealing with your specific problem. I don't have this specific issue, e.g. `curl -s "http://superuser.com"  | grep -E 'href="http://.*stackexchange\.com' | sed 's|^.*<a href="http://\([^"]*\)">.*$|http://\1|g' | grep -v "<" | xargs curl -s | grep "<title>"` works fine for me. (Yeah I know the code's extremely hacky).

Comment: Oh my.. I have to de-cypher that sed part in order to understand what you are doing, still it isn't working with jspider. I will start using perl now.

Comment: @StephanKristyn I extract URLs from hyperlinks, and since it doesn't work well enough, using `grep -v` I then remove all remaining lines with HTML tag brackets. Just a simple example that shows the approach works in general.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's untested but should work.

```
for a in $(./jspider.sh http://www.mypage.com | grep 'resource' | awk '{print $4}'); do curl $a | grep myString; done
```